# Filtrar um cabecalho dentro de df no pandas

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, lista, pandas

Sou novo no pandas e estou com uma grande dificuldade.
Preciso filtrar as colunas no meu dataframe, verificar se estão em uma lista definida e, caso estejam, agrupar as colunas e somar os valores. Parece simples, mas estou com muita dificuldade.
A primeira imagem foi como tentei fazer,porem deu errado. A segunda são meus dataframe e a terceira minha lista que preciso filtrar e retornar a soma das colunas dentro desta lista.
Desde já agradeço!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

´´´´

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(patch + 'PARTNER_23022021002403838.csv',sep=',',encoding='utf-8')
df = df.pivot_table('Value',df.index,['Flow','Country'])
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
grupos = {'Mundo' : ['Australia', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'Czech Republic',
      'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece',
      'Hungary', 'Iceland', 'Ireland', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'Korea',
      'Luxembourg', 'Mexico', 'Netherlands', 'New Zealand', 'Norway',
      'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Slovak Republic', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden',
      'Switzerland', 'Turkey', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Australia',
      'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'Czech Republic', 'Denmark',
      'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary',
      'Iceland', 'Ireland', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'Japan', 'Korea', 'Luxembourg',
      'Mexico', 'Netherlands', 'New Zealand', 'Norway', 'Poland', 'Portugal',
      'Slovak Republic', 'Slovenia', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland',
      'Turkey', 'United Kingdom', 'United States'],
        'Desenvolvidos' : ['United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Canada', 'Japan', 'Norway', 'Switzerland' ],
        'America Latina' : ['Chile','Mexico']}
paises = []
df_fim = pd.DataFrame()
for item in df.columns:
   if item in grupos['Mundo']:
       paises.append(item)
       df_resultado = df.loc[:,paises].sum(axis=1)
       df_fim = pd.concat([df_fim,df_resultado],axis=0)
       df_fim.rename(columns = {'0':'B'},inplace=True)

   else:
       print('erro')
```

Comment: João Victor, no lugar de imagens de código insira o próprio código na pergunta, existe um bloco para a indentação. Coloque também se possível o dataset para testes para as pessoas que forem tentar te ajudar. Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, sou novo aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o lmonferrari comentou, tendo parte do dado fica mais fácil de alguém ajudar.
Veja se isso ajuda:

Primeiro, vou gerar um dado falso com 4 colunas a, b, x, y com 5 linhas.

```
colunas_A = ['a', 'b']
colunas_B = ['x', 'y']

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i, col in enumerate(colunas_A + colunas_B):
    n = (i+1)*100
    df[col] = range(n,n+5)

print(df)
```

Em teoria você já tem a tabela e uma lista de colunas,
que no meu exemplo seriam as listas selecao1 e selecao2.
E agora a seleção com a soma por colunas:

```
selecao1 = ['a','x']
selecao2 = ['y','b']

soma_sel1 = df.filter(items=selecao1).sum(axis=1)
soma_sel2 = df.filter(items=selecao2).sum(axis=1)

df['soma_sel_1'] = soma_sel1
df['soma_sel_2'] = soma_sel2

print(df)
```